# How do I stylize ::selection in IE8?

Tags: css

I have a dark background and lighter text on a page. When someone selects the text, I want to have a lighter background and darker text. I'm using the following CSS for that:

**CSS**

```
p{
background: #aac;
color: white;
}

p::selection {
background: lime;
color: black;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and FF but breaks in IE8. How do I ensure that it works there as well?

Comment: @BackSlash that question did not show up in the set of related questions when I typed in the question. I am guessing that stackoverflow only matched the title with the existing titles. OTOH, that question and the question it links to and the page that links to - they all say unanimously that it can't be done. I think I'll just have to explain this to my team :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`::selection` isn't supported by IE8 and lower versions.**](http://caniuse.com/css-selection)

You would need some sort of a polyfill if you want it to be supported; however, it doesn't seem as though any existing polyfills offer support for such a selector.

Comment: I already figured out that it's not supported in IE < 9. Searching for polyfills for text selection is turning out to be a wild goose chase.

Comment: @KumudSinha I was checking out modernizr and shim, and neither seem to include it in their documentation..

Comment: Its just a style for selection and has nothing to do with functionality. Don't bend over backwards and spend hours trying to get your site to look identical in IE8. IE8 is a shitty browser so it gets shitty styles. If people don't like the way the site looks in IE8 then they should upgrade their browser. Sick of people trying to find workarounds for drop shadows, round corners, text shadow, etc.  This stuff is all aesthetics!!!

Comment: @zgood I totally agree. Now, only if everyone on the team gets it.

Comment: @zgood Couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: Ya I have wasted a good part of my life trying to get my websites to look like modern sites in a non-modern browser. Now I realize I was just adding to the problem by making users think that IE8 can render modern looking sites, when in reality it took a developer days just to get everything looking ok. Now I'm honest with them. When asked "Why does it look different in IE8", I reply "Because IE8 is an outdated browser. If you want it to look like a modern website in an out-dated browser I can do that, but it'll cost you days of work." All the sudden that rounded corner is no longer important!

Comment: @zgood Graceful degradation. You can barely browse the internet with an outdated browser anyways.